# mongoose cannot detect _id after import

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

if you export data from mongo db like {"_id":"5ee8b4b32af76531cd46d714"} and have problem to find it with Modal.findById(_id); see the complete answer...

Answer (score 1):

if you export data from mongo db like

`{"_id":"5ee8b4b32af76531cd46d714"}`

and have problem to find it with

`Modal.findById(_id);`

you should change your data and import it like

`{"_id":{"$oid":"5ee8b4b32af76531cd46d714"}`

to mongoDB recognize it objectId and find it by

`Model.findById(_id);`

Good Luck.